# Meaning of being stoked?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Jean-Michel lived like a flame. He burned very bright. Then the flame went out , but the embers are very hot. They are being stoked in an exhibition.

Stoke means add coal to a fire.
In here , is "stoke" a reference to "the embers are very hot"?

Does "being stoked" mean his artworks are getting displayed in this exhibition?

Answer (score 3):

To stoke a fire is to add fuel to it to make the fire larger. I assume the writer is referring to Jean-Michel Basquiat. The writer is saying that Jean-Michel's work is very bright and fiery, and that the exhibition makes his artwork even brighter and hotter. So, yes, the exhibition is displaying the artwork of Basquiat. The writer is trying to say that the exhibition is worth seeing.

Interestingly, ***to be stoked*** has an informal usage as well. If someone says "I'm stoked," it means they're really happy and excited about something. This slang usage is associated with surfer culture in the US, going back several decades. There used to be a surfer magazine called "Stoked": [https://www.amazon.com/Stoked-History-Surf-Culture-Kampion/dp/1586852132](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1586852132)